# google maps using API V2 with mapfragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am doing this tutorial about:Showing current location in Google Maps using API V2 with SupportMapFragment

I followed the steps carefully, but at the end the map doesn't appear, just a gray screen with longitude and latitude.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment

Comment: It seems an API_KEY issue. Please check if you are using correct key that you have created for your debug cert. I assume you have created it?

Comment: @aegean yes I created it and used it as the tutorial says

Comment: Are you running your app on a real device or emulator?

Comment: @aegean it now works fine :)

Comment: What was the problem then? Could you share. And how did that be solved?

Comment: @aegean when creating the API key, I just misspelled the package name

Comment: please do share solution I had a similar problem during my hackathon last week maybe we solved it differently i wud like to know how just incase

Comment: @Manny264 I can't add an answer before 10 hours of posting the question

Comment: ohh right coz of the reputations? ok will check 10hrs from now then

Comment: @Manny264 ok, I will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it :) 
when creating the API key, I just misspelled the package name